# Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function using dispatch with useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've been learning to use useContext and useReducer hooks with action & dispatch but I keep getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function" whenever I try to use the dispatch function from another context component:

This is the context component where I containing useReducer:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { useStateContext } from './StateContextProvider';

const CartStateContext = createContext(null);

export default function ReducerProvider({children}) {
    const { cartItems, updateCart, addToCart, quantity } = useStateContext();
    
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        let { type, payload, index } = action
        if(type === "ADD"){
            const existingProduct = state.find((item) => item.index === payload.id);
            if(existingProduct){
                let updatedCartItem = state.map(cartItem => {
                    if(cartItem.index === payload.index){
                        let newQty = cartItem.quantity + quantity
                        return {
                            ...cartItem,
                            quantity: newQty
                        }
                    } else {
                        return {
                            ...state
                        }
                    }
                })
                updateCart(updatedCartItem)
            } else {
                payload.quantity = quantity;
                addToCart(payload)
            }
        }
        if(type === "REMOVE"){
            const newArr = [...state];
            newArr.splice(index, 1);
            return newArr;
        }
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, cartItems);

    return (
        <CartStateContext.Provider value={{
            state,
            dispatch
        }}>
            {children}
        </CartStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useCartReducer = () => useContext(CartStateContext);
```

The code below is the context component I used the dispatch function:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useCartReducer } from './ReducerProvider';

export const StateContext = createContext()

export default function StateContextProvider({children}) {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
    const dispatch = useCartReducer();

    const increaseQty = () => {
      setQuantity(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }
    const decreaseQty = () => {
      setQuantity(prevState => prevState - 1)
      if(quantity <= 1) {
        setQuantity(1)
      }
    }
    const updateCart = (products) => {
      setCartItems(products)
    }
    const addToCart = (product) => {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, {...product}])
    }
    const onAddClick = (product, button) => {
      if(button.toLowerCase() === "buy now") {
        dispatch({type: "ADD", payload: product})
        handleCartClick()
      } else if(button.toLowerCase() === "add to cart") {
        dispatch({type: "ADD", payload: product})
      }
    }
    const handleRemoveCart = (index) => {
      dispatch({type: "REMOVE", payload: index})
    }
    
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{
        cartItems, 
        updateCart,
        addToCart,
        onAddClick,
        handleRemoveCart,
        quantity,
        increaseQty,
        decreaseQty,
    }}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  )
}
export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

Comment: Try this -  const {dispatch} = useCartReducer();

Comment: because if you console your dispatch that is not a value that is a object which contains dispatch as a key.

Comment: I dd this but now it's returning a different error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'dispatch' of '(0 , _ReducerProvider__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useCartReducer)(...)' as it is null." @GulshanAggarwal